# Unable to deploy release package to nexus using maven release:perform

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I am getting 400 errors when I try to execute maven release: perform.

[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project my-project: Failed to deploy artifacts: Cou
ld not transfer artifact com.acca.project:project:pom:1.0.0-RELEASE from/to acca-nexus (https://nexus.io/repository/project/): Failed to transfer file https://nexus.io/repository/project/myproject/myproject/1.0.0-RELEASE/myproject-1.0.0-RELEASE.pom with status code 400 -> [Help 1]

Following things I have tried 
1) I verified, credentials are correct
2) URL for nexus repo is correct
3) I am maintaining the proper 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT name
4) there is no package with the same version in nexus as well
5) Not a network issue as well, I can do maven deploy properly.

Release plugin -config looks like below

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <scmCommentPrefix>[maven-scm] :</scmCommentPrefix>
                <goals>deploy</goals>
                <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I want to deploy the package when I do maven release: perform, but I am unable to debug beyond this. can someone please tell me how to debug this. Pointing out the issue will also helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the above issue.

The solution was in the nexus repository configuration.
I updated the configuration to "allow redeploy" and it started working.

Thank you

Comment: How did you "allow redeploying"?  This "answer" doesn't help anyone